# Error: Unknown header type: 21

Tags: javascript

I am using google pie chart my `json` value is:

```
[
    ["Exhibitor Fee", 21], 
    ["Attendee Registration", 400], 
    ["Hotel Cost Per Night", 21212], 
    ["Sponsorship", 435], 
    ["Shippng", 456]
]
```

And my code is:

```
var jsonValues = '<?php echo $staticEvent; ?>'
var pieValues = $.parseJSON(jsonValues);
console.log(pieValues);
google.charts.load('current', {'packages': ['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(pieValues);

    var options = {
        title: 'My Daily Activities'

    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Comment: please create jsfiddle for your chart.

Answer (score 0):

by the looks of things [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#making-a-3d-pie-chart) the pie chart expects the first array to be the headers for your chart, which i would imagine should be strings, whereas your first array is `string, int`

Try changing your json to:

```
[
    ["Activity", "Cost"],
    ["Exhibitor Fee", 21], 
    ["Attendee Registration", 400], 
    ["Hotel Cost Per Night", 21212], 
    ["Sponsorship", 435], 
    ["Shippng", 456]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

how are you,

Try it:

in your php var $staticEvent; you change to:

```
<?php
     $staticEvent = json_encode($staticEvent, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
?>
```

And your JS:

```
var jsonValues = '<?php echo $staticEvent; ?>';
var pieValues = $.parseJSON(jsonValues);
console.log(pieValues);
google.charts.load('current', {'packages': ['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(pieValues);

    var options = {
        title: 'My Daily Activities'

    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```